# Cannot start live session or install on ROG GL552VW

Tags: boot, system-installation, 15.10

I've been having a lot of problems lately when trying to set up a second operating system on my Asus ROG GL552VW. 
When I try to start an installation or to get to the initial screen for that matter, I get prompted with the following message:
[Starting initial boot from USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXXRg.jpg)

I was getting this message when trying to install Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Gnome 15.10.

At first I was able to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but since the kernel version doesn't support all the drivers I tried upgrading it to v4.3.4, which just caused the installation to be unusable. I was hoping that installing 15.10 with newer kernel v4.1 or higher would help me avoid issues with the WiFi card being unrecognized, along with other driver issues I was experiencing.

As a side note, I am not able to install any Linux distro as they all get stuck after trying either to start live session/install or even trying to initiate that first screen where you can choose whether you want to start a live session or just install, and with every distro I get a different message.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New laptop (Skylake) cannot boot Xubuntu even with boot parameters](http://askubuntu.com/questions/694453/new-laptop-skylake-cannot-boot-xubuntu-even-with-boot-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install the Ubuntu daily live 16.04 version on the same laptop by using the following extra parameters at boot time:

```
nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_osi=! acpi_backlight=native idle=nomwait
```

Adding these parameters at boot solved the issue for me, allowing to install. The laptop is completely functional but it is overheating quite badly without any CPU load (maybe for missing driver, didn't debug this yet).