# Trouble with nvidia drivers on Asus ROG GL522

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gnome, 16.04

I was installing ubuntu-Gnome 16.04 on my Asus ROG GL522VW laptop with an nvidia GTX 960m graphics card, and stumbled upon a problem.

After installation, I don't even get to the login screen. Instead my screen just freezes.
I had this problem before, and got my answer in this post:
[Installing linux on ROG GL552VW (Beginner)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/757573/installing-linux-on-rog-gl552vw-beginner)

So I booted with nouveau.modeset=0, and everything boots just fine.
But after I use additional drivers to install the NVIDIA binary driver - version 361.42 from nvidia-361 (proprietary, tested), I only get a black screen when I try to boot regardless of whether nouveau.modeset=0 is set or not.

While the screen is black, when I try to access the command line with `ctrl + alt + f1` all I get is this:
`A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)`
and no matter how much I will wait, it doesn't end and I have to reboot.

I followed the instructions in this post: [Cannot boot system due to start job running for hold](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold)

When I boot after reinstalling everything and choosing lightdm - it basically works but my login screen looks like a unity login screen, and when I insert my credentials it shows me a very bugged screen with all kinds of broken images with some of the things I had on my last boot, and after a few seconds my screen flashes on and off and it boots into my normal desktop, but still keeps spitting out `system problem detected` with only the option to close or report.

Also tried to install nvidia-355 and all kinds of versions, with no luck.

I wouldn't mind working with `nouveau.modeset=0`, but as far as I understand this disables my graphics card and doesn't utilize all of it's potential?

Any help or insight will be greatly appreciated.
Sorry for the long post and if I should include more information please tell me what else I should include.

A huge thanks up front!

Edit:
Reposted this question again and didn't know I can just edit the question to get it back up.

Edit2: Bumping again in a last effort to solve this issue

Please let me know if it is lacking information.