# Nvidia drivers on Asus ROG GL522

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 16.04, nouveau

I posted this question a while ago ([Trouble with nvidia drivers on Asus ROG GL522](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814543/trouble-with-nvidia-drivers-on-asus-rog-gl522)) but got no answer I guess because the post was long so I'll try to keep it short this time.

After installing and booting with nouveau.modeset=0 I try to install the nvidia drivers usig additional drivers and only get black screen if I try to boot regardless if I use nouveau.modeset=0 or not.

during the black-screen mentioned above, when I try to access the command line all I get is

> A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin
>   Xs/no limit)

This post: [Cannot boot system due to start job running for hold](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold)

When I try to boot after using the solution in the post above with lightdm - I get a unity-like login screen, when I log in my screen shows a vert bugged version of itself for a few seconds, and which it starts correctly but then keeps spitting out

> system problem detected

I wouldn't mind working with nouveau.modeset=0 but from what I understand this doesn't utilize my graphics card at all?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't double post, there are ways you can get your post back on the front page, simply editing your other question would of done. Please read this http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3540/how-can-i-bump-my-unsolved-question

Comment: Can you post the details of "system problem detected"

Comment: @CedaEI Please contact the OP on the original question http://askubuntu.com/questions/814543/trouble-with-nvidia-drivers-on-asus-rog-gl522 this is a duplicate and will close soon.