# Impossible to boot or install from USB stick (Ubuntu 17.10 - ROG G20AJ)

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, uefi, live-usb

I want to install Ubuntu 17.10 on my Asus ROG G20AJ computer, equipped with the Nvidia GTX 980 Ti GPU and Intel Core i5 CPU.

I've taken a USB drive with a live CD Ubuntu version (that I've already used to install Ubuntu with success on a laptop PC, also Nvidia, Intel, and Windows-powered), but I stick on the GRUB.
I've disabled Secure Boot and Fast Boot. I enabled CSM and UEFI execution (my Windows system is installed with UEFI mode).

But by booting on the USB drive, I stick to the GRUB screen with any option (*Install Ubuntu* or *Try Ubuntu without installing*) broken.
Indeed, when I boot in both options, I'm faced with these errors and the PC doesn't continue to boot:

[image]

I've also tried to add `acpi=off nomodeset` options to both boot commands. Instead of that error logs, the computer gets stuck on a black screen indefinitely.

How can I make Ubuntu installable on my computer via the USB stick, since the latter works on another computer before without any problems?

Comment: A properly-made LiveUSB does not use GRUB, so your description seems suspect. Did you search for the meaning of those ACPI errors? Did the hardware work properly before you tried to install Ubuntu?

Comment: I search about those ACPI errors and found that these are apparently low-level harmless errors appearing since Ubuntu is more verbose in its last versions... Moreover I've got the same errors on my laptop but these didn't stop Ubuntu booting and installing (just an acpi=off and all these errors disappears). And yep, the hardware works great on Windows 10 already installed on the ROG.

Comment: Live USB Ubuntu installer uses grub2 for UEFI boot and syslinux for BIOS boot. If Windows is UEFI, you want to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI And with nVidia, you will at least need nomodeset. Older ROG thread, needed many boot parameters. https://askubuntu.com/questions/694453/new-laptop-skylake-cannot-boot-xubuntu-even-with-boot-parameters Some may not be required now. Is AHCi on? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380617

Comment: Exactly! Surprisingly, even nomodeset wasn't necessary for the other nVidia laptop (more recent than the ROG desktop) to run Ubuntu correctly, but that long line of parameters will certainly be mandatory on the desktop. I've tried all boot parameters on the page you linked and if there isn't booting yet the log changes => https://imgur.com/a/V9ccG AHCI is activated too