# BIOS Error: System crash when booting from live USB with bionic 18.04/ focal fossa 20.04 daily build

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, grub-efi

When booting from Live USB with Ubuntu 18.04.4 image, I've got the following error ~10 seconds after the GNOME shell was loaded:

[image]

This error leads to a system shutdown.

I've tried to select *Try Ubuntu without installing* and *Install Ubuntu*, both of them are giving the same error.

**UPD:**
This problem still persists (I've tried different ubuntu images and different disk creators). I've also tried to disable acpi with `acpi=off` in bootloader settings.

My system ASUS ROG Strix GL503GE laptop has the following drives:

- 256 GB SSD with Windows 10 installed
- 1 TB HDD with Ubuntu 19.10 installed

Comment: You have nVidia, are you using nomodeset boot parameter? Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Asus ROG Zephyrus G Ryzen 7 GTX 1660 Ti UEFI update required, nVidia driver required
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420199
Many also need pci=nomsi boot parameter. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414431 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @oldfred UEFI is at newest version. `nomodeset` parameter was added but also didn't work for me.

Comment: Both nomodeset pci=nomsi added to Linux line? This user even added more parameters? https://askubuntu.com/questions/694453/new-laptop-skylake-cannot-boot-xubuntu-even-with-boot-parameters

Answer (score 2):

### Boot Live USB using grub from Internal Drive

If you are having trouble booting a Live Ubuntu 19.10 USB made using balenaEtcher, mkusb, Startup Disk Creator, dd or other method that uses an ISO9660 file, you may be able to boot using your internal drives grub.

Try adding the following menuentry to your internal drive's grub menu or to /etc/grub.d/40_custom and then run sudo update-grub.:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu - flash drive" {
 search --set=root --fs-uuid xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   ($root)/casper/vmlinuz$casper_flavour  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed quiet splash  ---
    initrd  ($root)/casper/initrd$casper_flavour
}
```

Where xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx is the UUID of the Live USB.

This method should work for any live or Persistent USB that boots ISO9660 files.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this method

Comment: After choosing "Ubuntu - flash drive" from grub menu, I was dropped into initramfs shell with no gui . How to launch normal installation&

Comment: @arturkuchynski method did you use to make the Live usb USB? Is it an ISO9660 disk?

Comment: I've tried to made live usb using Rufus and Startup disk creator

Comment: C.S. Cameron this problem persists independently (I've tried different ubuntu images and different disk creators). I thonk that It's a BIOS error. I've also tried to disable acpi in bootloader.